# Working with 0.4.4 version of solidity, still got error, "Member 'transfer' not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in address."

Tags: solidity, remix, payable

According to some resources, this well known error occur because of versions 0.4.X to 0.5.X change.

Previously I compiled contract with ^0.5.1, to solve this error currently I'm using 0.4.4. But still the error is there.

```
  fundsWallet.transfer(msg.value);
```

Error:

> Error: Member "transfer" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in address
>           fundsWallet.transfer(msg.value);
>           ^------------------^

I have also changed my declaration, 
from:

```
address public fundsWallet;
```

to

```
address public payable fundsWallet;
```

still error is:

> Error: Expected identifier, got 'Payable'

How can I fix this issue in version ^0.4.4 as well as ^0.5.1?

Comment: In 0.5.x, you can just use `address payable public fundsWallet;`. (You had "public" and "payable" reversed. In 0.4.4, there's no such thing as `address payable`. Share the rest of your code if you need help there.

Comment: I've referred this contract from given link: https://etherscan.io/address/0x4ed6d830c630323652f8b993b5ba0446b533994f#code

Comment: As that page indicates, it was compiled with the version `v0.4.19+commit.c4cbbb05`. It compiles fine under that version now too. In 0.4.4, I don't think `address.transfer` existed yet.

Comment: Yes, I've changed version from 0.4.4 to 0.4.19. Thank you for answer.